# m2e subclipse connector - deprecated?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e, subclipse

I want to use m2e in connection with subclipse in Eclipse Mars. Unfortunately, the subclipse connector was eliminated from the Discovery Catalog of m2e.

Nevertheless, I got a running configuration by using Subclipse 1.8 (pretty old) together with the update site

http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0

On

https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg05356.html

one gets the impression that the subclipse connector is kind of "deprecated" and cannot be used with the newer versions of subclipse.

My question: Is there a non-deprecated way to use subclipse in connection with m2e?